# ember-cli and ember-simple-auth setup for testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am using `ember-simple-auth` with `ember-cli`. I can't figure out how to pass authentication during integration tests are running.

In my startApp I lookup for session from container then set `isAuthenticated` property to true but i guess it is not enough.

I reopen Session in initializer and add computed property user. For testing this one also should not look for store.

```
Session.reopen({
  user: function() {
    var userId = this.get('user_id');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
      return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
    }
  }.property('userId')
});
```

And also I guess local-storage is not proper for testing so how to set store type to `store:ephemeral` when tests are running.

I could not find any complete tutorial or anything about writing integration test when using ember-cli and ember-simple-auth. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm currently working on some improvements for Ember Simple Auth's testability and also a tutorial on how to sea it up.

Comment: If you have a road map I would love to contribute if I can

Comment: There's no road map really but you can checkout the testing branch: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[marcoow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527893/marcoow) has now released the official [Ember Simple Auth Testing library](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-testing)